# Bootstrap added to the list of includes

Tags: feature-request

The code editor includes jQuery, Knockout, Angular and d3.
Can Twitter Bootstrap be added as well?
I don't think there's any need to include version 2, but you decide.

Comment: Do you mean on Stack Snippets?